# How can I add a field's length for the sort in Model?

Tags: python, django

How can I add a field's length for the sort in `Model`?

I have an IPv4Manage model:

```
class IPv4Manage(models.Model):
    """
    ipv4
    """
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(help_text="ip")
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ip']
```

In the Meta we can set the ordering criteria with the fields.

But I have a question, can I set the `ip`'s length for order in the `Model`?

I know if in the APIView I can use `Prefetch` or `extra` for the length of the `ip` and order it.

```
...extra(select={'length':'Length(ip)'}).order_by('length', 'ip')
```

But can we set the length of field param of order in the `Model`?

---

**EDIT-1**

I created a Manager:

```
class IPv4ManageManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(length=Length('ip')).order_by('length', 'ip')
```

and I add it to the default Manager, it works for me.

```
class IPv4Manage(models.Model):
    """
    ipv4
    """
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(help_text="ip")
    ...

    objects = IPv4ManageManager()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ip']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 2.0 you can use query expresions with [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length

class IPv4Manage(models.Model):
    """
    ipv4
    """
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(help_text="ip")
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = [Length('ip').asc()]
```

Comment: Is there a method for Django 1.x?

Comment: @qg_java_17137 Try to implement custom manager. Just add ordering to the `get_queryset` method. Look at this doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset